# getting the numbers entered in textbox in an array

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, textbox, numbers

how can i get the numbers entered in textbox in an array.

for example:

user enter 33,21,5,8 in textbox

and i want to make an array with this numbers,how can i do it?thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Int32[] numbers = textbox1.Text.Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

to get the first item, use following code:

```
Int32[] numbers = textbox1.Text.Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
Int32 firstNumber = numbers.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void ConvertStringToArray(string p)
{
string[] CardsToBeSortedArray = p.Split(',');
int[] IntCard = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(CardsToBeSortedArray, delegate(string
card)
{
int result;
int32.TryParse(card, out result);
return result;
});
}
```